# Share files/directories by setgid

Tags: administration, setgid

> To allow write access to a specific group, shared files/folders can be made writeable by default for everyone in this group and the owning group can be automatically fixed to the group which owns the **parent directory** by setting the setgid bit on this directory:
>
> `chmod g+s our_shared_directory`
>
> Otherwise the file creator's default group (usually the same as the user name) is used.

The above quote is from [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Users_and_groups#User_management). It is not clear to me how to make shared files and folders. Say user **A** and **B** both belong to a common group **G**. Now how do I create `our_shared_directory` such that by default everyone in **G** has write permission?

Second, why do I need `setgid` on `our_shared_directory`? Why do I need to make the owning group fixed to group of the **parent directory** of `our_shared_directory`?

Comment: I suspect the phrase *shared files and folders* has no technical meaning, its not like there is a command `makefileshared <file>`. I think its meant in a practical context. i.e. files that are used  by all users, e.g.  documentation files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to share control of a folder between

- user `a`
- user `b`

Create the users

```
 % sudo adduser a
Adding user `a' ...
Adding new group `a' (1002) ...
Adding new user `a' (1001) with group `a' ...
Creating home directory `/home/a' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
....
```

and

```
% sudo adduser b
Adding user `b' ...
```

Make a directory

```
% mkdir our_shared_directory
```

Create a new group and add the users to it

```
 % sudo addgroup cool_kids
Adding group `cool_kids' (GID 1001) ...
Done.
 % sudo adduser a cool_kids            
Adding user `a' to group `cool_kids' ...
Adding user a to group cool_kids
Done.
% sudo adduser b cool_kids
....
```

Make the directory belong to the `cool_kids` group and `setgid` bit

```
sudo chmod g+s our_shared_directory
sudo chown -v ubuntu:cool_kids our_shared_directory
```

check our work

```
ls -al
drwxrwsr-x 2 ubuntu cool_kids  40 Feb 29 20:37 our_shared_directory/
      ^ setgid bit is set and group is now "sticky"
```

Look what happens when a file is  made by user `a` in a normal directory

```
% touch file_made_by_user_a
% ls -al
-rw-rw-r-- 1 a      a           0 Feb 29 20:57 file_made_by_a
```

now user `a` create a file in `our_shared_directory`

```
% cd our_shared_directory/
% ls -al
-rw-rw-r-- 1 a      cool_kids  0 Feb 29 20:59 another_by_a
                     ^^^^^^ note the group
```

#### Important

1. **The cool_kids** group *automatically* applied to the new file

Now switch to user `b`

```
% su b
Password: ...
```

**b can now edit the file made by a** - because the `another_by_a` file has default mode of `-rw-rw-r--` ,`b` could not normally edit it.
But with

```
b% vim another_by_a
^ note this means we are user "b"   now  
[make some edit and save]
```

`b` was able to modify the file **because b belonged to the group `cool_kids` and because `cool_kids` was guaranteed to be applied to the new file by the `setgid` bit

```
ls -al
-rw-rw-r-- 1 a      cool_kids  7 Feb 29 21:03 another_by_a
                               ^ the file is 7bytes - slightly bigger because of changes made by b
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, but for me, any new directories or files under the `setgid` directory do *not* have group write permissions. However, in your example, both files and directories do.  Are you sure you're not using ACLs or masks here?